# How to inherit Payment screen and add validation in _finalizeValidation()

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15

I want to inherit `_finalizeValidation()` method from the `paymentscreen` of `odoo15` in which I just want to add a condition that if the `invoice` is selected in the `payment screen` then the `validate button` will function and will move on to the receipt screen else will give a user error, and I am not getting  a way to inherit and do so, Any help in this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example in the [pos_hr](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/pos_hr/static/src/js/PaymentScreen.js) module where they inherit the `_finalizeValidation` function to set the employee on the current order:

```
odoo.define('pos_hr.PaymentScreen', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    const PaymentScreen = require('point_of_sale.PaymentScreen');
    const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');

    const PosHrPaymentScreen = (PaymentScreen_) =>
          class extends PaymentScreen_ {
              async _finalizeValidation() {
                  this.currentOrder.employee = this.env.pos.get_cashier();
                  await super._finalizeValidation();
              }
          };

    Registries.Component.extend(PaymentScreen, PosHrPaymentScreen);

    return PaymentScreen;
});
```

Comment: Thank you.....you always save my day...